# How should i correct my proxy settings for my code to become correct?

Tags: python, proxy, download

I am trying to download a pic from a site with python 3. I get access to net via proxy.
My login is in format "Corpname/Surname"
My proxy server is gateway.corpname.local, port 8080
When i run the following code, i get an error described below the code.
What am i doing wrong?

```
import urllib.request as req
def getPictureByURL(url,path):
    arg={'http':r'http://CorpName/Surname:Password@gateway.corpname.local:8080'}
    proxy = req.ProxyHandler(arg)
    auth = req.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
    opener = req.build_opener(proxy, auth, req.HTTPHandler)
    req.install_opener(opener)
    conn = req.urlopen(url)
    return_str = conn.read()
def getExtensionOfFile(address):
    a=address.rfind(".")
    return address[a+1:]
def createPath(folder,number,extension):
    return folder+str(number)+"."+extension
def main():
    url=r"http://image.slidesharecdn.com/tcp-ip-130612050038-phpapp02/95/tcp-ip-3-pdf-1-638.jpg"
    folder=r"C:/Windows"+"/"
    ext=getExtensionOfFile(url)
    path=createPath(folder,1,ext)
    print(req.getproxies())
    print(url)
    print(path)
    getPictureByURL(url,path)
main()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\file.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\file.py", line 47, in main
    getPictureByURL(url,path)
  File "C:\file.py", line 32, in getPictureByURL
    conn = req.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 156, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 469, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 487, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 447, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1268, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1251, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxy that your corp uses requires [NTLM authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager). It's not the standard [basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). So you can't use `urllib.request.ProxyHandler` to set up the proxy directly.

You may use other softwares like [Cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) to transform your corp's proxy to a standard http proxy.

Comment: thank you, but how did you manage to know that our proxy requires NTLM? I did not provide much data

Comment: @Juggernaut Because your username is `Corpname/Surname`.